# How to handle Array Object in List Grid? [SmartGWT]

Tags: java, smartgwt, listgrid

I have a `SelectItem` which was set to multiple as the editor for the column.
The values are saved in a `String[]` object.

As the editor is on non-edit mode, it shows the memory address of that object.
How could I handle it to show the value in the array, or is there anywhere I can set for this column to always show its editor?

[image: example image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the java class [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html), a static `toString` method is provided for you to print the content of an array.

`String arrayAsString = Arrays.toString(inputArray);`